# Show that $(D^\bot)^\bot=D$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $D$ be a non-empty subset of Hilbert space $H$. I need to find $(D^\bot)^\bot$. I guess $(D^\bot)^\bot=D$. We have that $D \subseteq (D^\bot)^\bot$ and that $D^\bot$ is a closed linear subspace of . But for the other inclusion I have problems. Many thanks for your help!

Edit: $D$ is not assumed to be closed!

Comment: Is $D$ assumed to be closed? Because $(D^\bot)^\bot$ always is.

Comment: Also, $(D^\bot)^\bot$ is always a linear subspace, and you've let $D$ be just a subset.

Comment: The point is $D$ is not assumed to be closed.

Comment: Then there is no way that $(D^\bot)^\bot=D$. Your title is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $F$ the closed linear span, $\overline{\text{span}(D)}$ of $D$. We claim that $(D^\perp)^\perp=F$. Write $H$ as $F\oplus F^\perp$. Then, $D\subseteq (D^\perp)^\perp$ implies $F\subseteq (D^\perp)^\perp$. Hence, we are only left with the other inclusion. Pick $h\in (D^\perp)^\perp$ decompose $h$ as
$$\tag{1}h=h_1+h_2\, \ \ ,\ h_1\in F,\, h_2\in F^\perp$$
Now, $h_2\in F^\perp=(\overline{\text{span}(D)})^\perp$. Also, $D\subseteq \overline{\text{span}(D)}$ implies $(D^\perp)^\perp \subseteq \bigl((\overline{\text{span}(D)})^\perp\bigr)^\perp$. Hence, since $h\in (D^\perp)^\perp$ implies $h\in \bigl((\overline{\text{span}(D)})^\perp\bigr)^\perp$. Which means that $\langle h,h_2\rangle =0$. Taking inner products in $(1)$ with $h_2$ and using $\langle h_1,h_2\rangle =0$ we obtain
$$||h_2||^2=\langle h,h_2\rangle -\langle h_1,h_2\rangle =0$$
Hence, $h_2=0$ and $h=h_1 \in F$. Which means that $(D^\perp)^\perp \subseteq F$.

A mini example which shows that $D \subsetneq (D^\perp)^\perp$, is to take as $D$ the space $c_{00}$ as a subspace of $\ell_2$. Then, its easy to check that $D$ is dence in $\ell_2$. Hence, $(D^\perp)^\perp= \overline{D}=\ell_2$ and of course $D=c_{00}\subsetneq \ell_2$.

Comment: We have that $D \subseteq F$, why we have then $D\subseteq (D^\perp)^\perp$ implies $F\subseteq (D^\perp)^\perp$?

Comment: $(D^\perp)^\perp$ is a closed linear space containing $D$, hence $F=\overline{\text{span}(D)}\subseteq (D^\perp)^\perp$.